# Using Onchange event in drop down list which triggers changes on another dropdown

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am looking for any sample code in visual force page. Where a change in a dropdown list should load data for the next dropdown. And the data should be loaded from the controller without reloading the page(AJAX)

Comment: Where the data will store? Are both picklist values are in same object or different object?

Answer (score 3):

Below code works!!

```
<apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!dropdown1}" required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="1" itemLabel="First"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="2" itemLabel="Second"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="dropdown2" action="{!change}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <br/>
    <apex:selectList id="dropdown2"  required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
        </apex:selectList>&nbsp;


public String dropdown1{get; set;}
public List<SelectOption> options;

public void  change()
{

    if(dropdown1 == '1')
    {
        options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('1','Value 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('2','Value 2'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('3','Value 3'));

    }
    else if(dropdown1 == '2')
    {
        options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('1','Case 1'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('2','case 2'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('3','case 3'));

    }

   }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        return options;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using dependent picklist.But if you want to set the options using controller,you can use the below code

```
<label>  SelectList1 Label:</label>
               <apex:selectList id="SelectList1"  size="1" value="{!SelectList1value}">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectList1List}"/>
                   <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="SelectList2"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            <label>  SelectList2 Label: </label>
                <apex:outputpanel id="SelectList2">
                 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!SelectList2Value}">
                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectList2List}"/>
                 </apex:selectList>
                </apex:outputpanel>

           //Controller code
            public string SelectList1value{get;set;}
            public string SelectList2Value{get;set;}
            public List<SelectOption> getSelectList1List() 
            {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('1','option 1'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('2','option 2'));
            return options;
            }   


            public List<SelectOption> getSelectList2List() 
            {  
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            if(SelectList1value==null)
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption('1','option 1'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('2','option 2'));
            }
            else
            if(SelectList1value=='2')
            {
                options.add(new SelectOption('1','option 1'));
                options.add(new SelectOption('2','option 2'));
            }
            return options;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same purpose you can use `Field Dependencies`
Please check [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_creating_picklists.htm&language=en_US) to see how you can use `Field Dependency`.